# How to access Android resources e.g. dimensions in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx, resources

I need to get dimensions defined in XML files under Android folder from classes in Core directory of libgdx.

I know I can use assets folder for accessing drawables. But how about dimensions or strings?

Comment: Why negative vote? If you don't understand the question, just leave it. I bet those who gave negative vote don't even know what is libgdx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access this kind of platform specific information directly in the core project. But this can be achieved by interfacing these functions with a Facade, providing a platform-specific implementation for each target.

[In libgdx-wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) there is an example for platform specific interfaces.

```
public interface PlatformSpecificStuff {
    public String getString();
    public int getDimensions();
}

// In -Android project
public class AndroidSpecificStuff implements PlatformSpecificStuff {
    public String getString(){
        // do whaterver you want with the resources.
        return "string resource";
    }

    public int getDimensions(){
        // do whaterver you want with the resources.
        return 42;
    }
}

// In -Desktop project
public class DesktopSpecificStuff implements PlatformSpecificStuff {
    public String getString(){
        // there is no xml or any andorid specific resource
        return null;
    }

    public int getDimensions(){
        // there is no xml or any andorid specific resource
        return 0;
    }
}

public class MyGame implements ApplicationListener {
    private final PlatformSpecificStuff pss;

    public MyGame(PlatformSpecificStuff pss) {
        this.pss= pss;
    }
}
```

---

**Update**: I don't know what are trying to accomplish by getting the dimensions as android resources. But you are probably in wrong track. If you want to support multiple screen sizes, have a look at [viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)

Comment: I knew it must be somewhere in the docs, but I just could not find it. Thanks!